# sick leave table using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't figure out what the problem which cause "type mismatch" error
when i click the command button for the first time it shows the error , when i click again it works fine.
so can u help me to figure out what cause this error

red circle in the line which cause the error
[image]
[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const cStart As Long = 5
    Const cEnd As Long = 6
    Const cDura As Long = 8
 ' Define Workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   Dim srg As Range 'range refer to cell/multiple cells/row/column
    Dim Sec As Range
    Set srg = wb.Worksheets("info").Range("A2").CurrentRegion 'all data
     Set Sec = wb.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
     ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value  'variant any type of data
     Dim Dataa As Variant: Dataa = Sec.Value
     Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1) ' Source Number of Rows , UBound return size ofarray
     Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2) ' return Number of Columns
     
     
     
      ' Define Days Array.
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(2 To srCount) 'array, ReDim increase number without deleting previous data
    Dim countDura As Variant: ReDim countDura(srCount)
    Dim rrCount As Long: rrCount = 1 ' Result Array Row Counter - 1 for headers
    Dim cDiff As Long ' Days Between First and Last incl.
    Dim dura As Long
    Dim i As Long ' Data (Source) Array Rows
    Dim d As Long
    
      ' Calculate Result Array Rows Count and populate Days Array.
    For i = 2 To srCount
        cDiff = DateDiff("M", Data(i, cStart), Data(i, cEnd)) + 1
        dData(i) = cDiff
        rrCount = rrCount + cDiff
    
    
    Next i
    
    For d = 3 To srCount
    dura = Data(d, cEnd) - Data(d, cStart)
    countDura(d) = dura
    rrCount = rrCount + dura
   
    Next d
      
    
     ' Define Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rrCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim k As Long: k = 1 ' Result Array Rows Counter - 1 for headers
    
     ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim j As Long ' Data and Result Array Columns Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Repeat Counter

' Write headers.
    For j = 1 To cCount
        Result(1, j) = Data(1, j)
    Next j

 ' Write 'body'.
    For i = 2 To srCount 'row
    
        For n = 1 To dData(i) 'diff

            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To cCount 'column
                Select Case j
                Case cStart  'column 5 (started date)
                    If dData(i) = 1 Then  'print the same dates if the diff is 1
                        Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                        Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                        
                         Else
                        If n = 1 Then
                            Result(k, j) = Data(i, j) 'the first row of diff then change last date of month
                            Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Data(i, j))

                            Else
                            If n = dData(i) Then 'if n = diff , change first date depnd on last date(last row of diff)
                                Result(k, j) = dateFirstInMonth(Data(i, cEnd))
                                Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                                Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)

                                 Else ' previous empty row
                                Result(k, j) = Result(k - 1, cEnd) + 1
                                Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Result(k, j))
                                 Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)

                                   End If
                                   End If
                                   End If

                Case Is <> cEnd  ' not equal
'
                    Result(k, j) = Data(i, j) '' print rest of data
                    Result(k, cDura) = Data(i, cDura)
                    
    
                End Select

                  
            Next j
        Next n
    Next i
  
    With wb.Worksheets("new").Range("A1").Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(k).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - k + 1).Offset(k).ClearContents
         
         Dim shDest As Worksheet
         Set shDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("new")
         Dim last_row As Variant
         last_row = shDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         Dim daysDura As Variant
         Dim countDur As Variant: ReDim countDur(last_row)
        
            For i = 2 To last_row 'row
               shDest.Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
               daysDura = DateDiff("d", Dataa(i, cStart), Dataa(i, cEnd))
               countDur(i) = daysDura
               shDest.Cells(i, 8).Value = countDur(i)
              Next i

   End With
 
End Sub

Function dateFirstInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    dateFirstInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
End Function

Function dateLastInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    If Month(d) = 12 Then
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), 12, 31)
    Else
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1) - 1
    End If
End Function
```

The code is to shows the leave dates and calculate the number of days between the dates

Comment: `Debug.Print Dataa(i, cSTart)` and `Debug.Print Dataa(i, cEnd)` to see if they are valid inputs for `DateDiff`.

Comment: For readability and maintainability, try defining all your arrays by actual types and not variant that allows varying types. See MSDN docs: [Using arrays (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays).

Comment: still the same issue, what makes it work in the second press??not in the first press!! with the same values. @Parfait

Comment: Did you do as advised by @BigBen? See output in Immediate Window (Ctrl+G). The first pass may be sending incorrect date types.

Comment: yes i check the values in the first pass and it is incorrect , but in the second pass it will be the same row and same column but with correct values .how come ? @Parfait

Comment: Maybe you are changing data with each command click? Your code is extensive without data to be sure.

Comment: no it is the same data for the same row/column , in the first pass it is incorrect but in the second pass correct . i still couldn't figure out what the type that i wrote is wrong  @Parfait